# How should I arrange artificial logs, and should they become sooty?

Tags: wood, fireplace, chimney

There is a chimney powered by natural gas:

[image: chimney image]

I'm using fake woodchops which are made of some sort of cooked clay. I have two problems:

- I don't know what is the proper way to arrange fake woodchops on top of fire. Is there a proper way of structuring them on fire?
- Fake woodchops got black color on them after just a few hours of being used. Is something wrong with chimney? I noticed chimney is affecting things around it like wall and glass by turning their color to black. Might chimney be too smokey? Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Are you certain that those artificial logs are meant to be used in a fire?

Comment: @Matthew I bought them at a chimney shop. I'm pretty sure :)

Comment: What is the source of the flame?  Assuming it is gas, but thought I would make sure.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yes, it is natural gas.

Answer (score 2):

Real wood goes black as well - products of combustion commonly called soot.

If the device is set properly then there will be some, but if there seems to be a lot then get the device checked.

Comment: I would think that if the burner is working correctly there should be no soot from natural gas.  I think the soot is an indication that something is wrong.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I suspect the same. Not sure if there is a chimney specialist in our area though.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding arrangement of artificial logs...

Most kits come with a diagram showing the intended arrangement, and they're designed to fit a particular burner. If you don't have that, just be sure that you're not completely blocking any ports on the burner. Otherwise it's mostly a matter of decorative preference.